# Problem in finding the right answer

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A hand of 5 cards is chosen uniformly at random from a standard deck of 52
cards. Define the event
$A$ = the hand has at least one Ace". Determine $\Pr(A)$?

What is wrong with these Answers?

Answer 1:

We are going to determine $\Pr(A)$. Event $A$ states 
that the hand has 
at least one Ace. By symmetry, we may assume that $A$ is the 
event that the hand has the Ace of spades. Since there are 
${52}\choose 5$ hands of five cards and exactly ${51} \choose 4$ 
of them contain the Ace of spades, it follows that 
$\Pr(A)$ = $\frac{51 \choose 4}{52 \choose 5}$ = 
            $\frac{5}{52}$

Answer 2:

We are going to determine $\Pr(A)$ using 
the Law of Total 
Probability. 
For each $x \in \{ \spadesuit, \heartsuit, \clubsuit, \diamondsuit \}$, 
we define the event 
$ B_x $="the hand has the Ace of suit $x$"
We observe that 
$\Pr(B_x) = \frac{{{51} \choose 4}}{{{52} \choose 5}} = 
               \frac{5}{52}. $
We next observe that 
$\Pr(A \mid B_x) = 1 ,$
because if event $B_x$ occurs, then event $A$ also occurs. 
Thus, using the Law of Total Probability, we get 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
 \Pr(A) & = & \sum_x \Pr(A \mid B_x) \cdot \Pr(B_x) \\ 
        & = & \sum_x  1 \cdot \Pr(B_x) \\ 
        & = & \sum_x \frac{5}{52} \\ 
        & = & 4 \cdot \frac{5}{52} \\
        & = & \frac{5}{13} . 
\end{eqnarray*}

If both answers are wrong,then, what is $\Pr(A)$? Thanks

Comment: The probability of at least one Ace is substantially bigger than the probability the hand has the Ace of spades. The easiest approach is to find first the probability the hand does not contain an Ace.

Comment: What is wrong with those answers?

Comment: I explained why informally the first answer is wrong. You found correctly the probability the hand has the Ace of spades. Suppose that A will be happy only if the hand has the Ace of spades, and B will be happy if the hand has one or more Aces of any kind. It is clear that B will be happy more often than A.

Comment: The second answer is wrong because it double-counts the hands that have two Aces. So one must adjust by subtracting the two Ace hands. One will likely subtract too much, because of the three Ace hands, and so on.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. What about the second answer? Also, I figured out how to get $\Pr(A)$. But I don't think it is quite easy to represent it as a fraction so as to compare it with the second answer.

Comment: Calculating $1-\frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$ is not too hard. You will find it is *less* than your second answer, because your second answer double-counts.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you explain in a more detail why the second answer with the law of total probability over-counts?

Comment: Because it added the number of hands that have the Ace of spades to the number that had the Ace of hearts to the number that had the Ace of diamonds, to the number that had the Ace of clubs. In the sum of the count for spades and hearts, we counted twice the hands that had the Ace of spades **and** the Ace of hearts. Same with the other combinations of two. And we counted three times the hands that have an Ace occurring $3$ times. And we counted four times the hands that have an Ace occurring $4$ times.